# What is the word for a mentally handicapped elder?

Tags: single-word-requests

In other words, what is the word used when someone becomes so old they cant function properly, like sitting in a chair staring off into space, completely ignoring their surroundings you know?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your "cant" is ill-written.;

Comment: Hmm, the dupe’s green-checked answer is -1; an answer rated 1 is in effect the same—demented. Is that really a good answer?